# Preposition in and on regarding clothes

Tags: prepositions

Hi I tried to look for a grammatical explanation for the usage of "in" and "on" in this context (please see examples below) but I couldn't find any. Why is
 sentence A and C are correct but sentence B and D are wrong?

> A) The girl in the red dress.                                                        
>  B) The girl on the red dress.                                                          
>  C) The girl with the red dress on.                                                               
>  D) The girl with the red dress in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an article of clothing **on** means to be wearing it.

This pattern

> The {person} **with a** {article of clothing}  **on**

can be understood as

> The {person} **with a** {article of clothing}  **on** {the person}

So you can see that the preposition **in** would not work there:

> The {person} **with a** {article of clothing}  **in** {the person}
>
> The girl with a red dress **in** [her] <sup>ungrammatical</sup>
>
> The girl with a red dress **on** [her] <sup>OK</sup>

To be **in** an article of clothing also means to be wearing it, but the person is inside the clothing.  With **on**, the clothing is on the outside of the person. It is simply a matter of how one conceptualizes clothing: are we in it or is it on us?

Answer (score 0):

A and C are correct if the right answer is "which sentences mean the girl is wearing the dress."

Only D is really wrong.

> The girl in the red dress

*X in Y* is used when Y surrounds X on a couple or more sides, or Y is a container of some sort.  This means the same as "The girl wearing the red dress."

> The girl on the red dress

*X on Y* is used when Y is flat and X is above it and making contact with it. 
 So this means the girl is sitting/standing on top of the dress, not wearing it.

> The girl with the red dress on

*On* here is being used as an adverb to mean "physically in contact with and supported by a surface", which is also used to mean "that is being worn by her."

> The girl with the red dress in

*In* can similarly be used as an adverb to mean "that is inside of X".   Unless the word "girl" means "something that is shaped like a girl but can be used to contain items" this sentence won't make any sense since you cannot put a dress inside of a girl.

Comment: Sorry forgot to make it clearer. The context is that a girl who is standing on the floor is wearing a red dress. So by this context I assume "B" is wrong?